# jquery-ui selectable on angular

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I am trying to create a grid game and need to capture the cells that are "selected". For this, I am using jQuery-ui. But my divs are not getting populated by the selectable classes at all. This is how my view looks:

```
<div ng-show="started">
    <div class="board selectable">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="row in board" ng-init="makeBoardSelectable()" >
            <div class=" ui-state-default" ng-repeat="col in row ">{{col}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is how it looks in the controller:

```
$scope.makeBoardSelectable = function(){
    $scope.apply(function(){
        $('.board').selectable();
    });
    console.log('board row selectable');
};
```

I am not sure if I even have to put `$('.board').selectable();` in `$scope.apply()` since the div would exist when it calls `makeBoardSelectable` but I added that for good measure. The problem I feel is that nothing is being logged on the console as well i.e. `makeBoardSelectable` is not being called. What am I doing wrong? Does this code look allright otherwise?

Comment: Why don't you use the ngSelectable plugin here: https://github.com/willgm/ngSelectable

Comment: The source code is pretty simple too, maybe you can learn something from it: https://github.com/willgm/ngSelectable/blob/master/src/ngSelectable.js

Comment: I will look into it thanks. But I want to solve this apparent mystery!